# Use sprite image in ul list?

Tags: css, background, html-lists, sprite

Im trying to change my ul li list to use it with background image & sprites, but i have this problem with background-repeat, what i'm missing?

http://jsfiddle.net/R7MU4/

Comment: What is the problem? Getting a good answer starts with asking [a good question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx).

Comment: The background sprite repeats on all ul list as you can see in the example

Comment: The sprite is not repeating, just more of it is being shown because the height of the list items is greater than one of the sprite images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your sprite is tiled vertically, you need to use an element that will have a height equal to that of each of the sprite images.

One option is to use another element, like a span, and apply the background to that.
http://jsfiddle.net/mestekweb/R7MU4/2/

You could also apply the style to the link element.
http://jsfiddle.net/mestekweb/R7MU4/3/

In both cases, you'll have to adjust the margins and padding of the lists and/or links to compensate.

Comment: Thank you, the link element seems the best solution